# Spring @MockBean not injected with Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, mockito

I'm implementing a `SchedulerService` that uses a `AgentRestClient` bean to get some data from an external system. It looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class SchedulerService {

  @Inject
  private AgentRestClient agentRestClient;

  public String updateStatus(String uuid) {
    String status = agentRestClient.get(uuid);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

To test this service, I'm using Cucumber while at the same time I'm trying to mock the behavior of `AgentRestClient` using Spring Boot's `@MockBean` annotation, as follows:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CentralApp.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.company.project.cucumber.stepdefs", "cucumber.api.spring"})
public class RefreshActiveJobsStepDefs {

  @MockBean
  private AgentRestClient agentRestClient;

  @Inject
  private SchedulerService schedulerService;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    given(agentRestClient.get(anyString())).willReturn("FINISHED");//agentRestClient is always null here
  }

  //Skipping the actual Given-When-Then Cucumber steps...
}
```

When I try to run any Cucumber scenario, the `agentRestClient` is never mocked/injected. The `setUp()` method fails with a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.company.project.cucumber.stepdefs.scheduler.RefreshActiveJobsStepDefs.setUp(RefreshActiveJobsStepDefs.java:38)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
  at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
  at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

To get to this point I followed the following 2 resources, but still no luck getting it working:

- https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

The culprit seems to be Cucumber integration into Spring, because when I try the same approach with a plain JUnit `@Test` method, mocking works as expected.

So could you please tell me what Cucumber or Spring configuration have I missed or misunderstood?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below, and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I found out that the `@MockBean` annotation is ignored because I was running the tests with Cucumber instead of running them through Spring Boot. Duh...

So I replaced `@MockBean` with `@Mock`, and then I manually inject that mock into my service layer.

So now my test looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CentralApp.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class RefreshActiveJobsStepDefs {

  @Inject
  private SchedulerService schedulerService;

  @Mock
  private AgentRestClient agentRestClient;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   given(agentRestClient.get(anyString())).willReturn("FINISHED");
   schedulerService.setAgentRestClient(agentRestClient);
  }
  //Skipping the actual Given-When-Then Cucumber steps...
}
```

As you can see I've also removed the `@CucumberOptions(glue=...)` annotation, and now I make sure to pass it though the runner, which for CLI would be by using the `--glue` option.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This workaround works but don't allow permit the same feature as MockBean (override bean definition)

Comment: so we have not found any better solution yet? @pierrefevrier

Comment: @inquisitive you might find my answer useful, if you still want to use Cucumber with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 5):

@3wj's approach works for me.
In my case, the bean is optionally inject into a controller. Looks in this case, @MockBean will not work, I guess the reason is the bean is not hard referenced. Add a additional annotation @Autowired to make the bean hard referenced, then Spring will initialize the bean.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    public MyController(@Autowired(required = false) IMyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/the/path")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
        if(this.myService==null){
            //Throw service unavaillable exception
        }
        String data = this.myService.getData();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyControllerIT {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @MockBean
    private IMyService myService 

    @Test
    public void testQuery() throws Exception {
        // restTemplate to call rest API....
    }

}
```

Comment: Using @Autowired solved my issue. i m using cucumber 5.7.0. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too (Cucumber 6.9.1)

Comment: @PTT for me this inject to actual bean, not mocked bean, any clue ?

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this issue in 2023 and managed to solve it thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1470#issuecomment-638688625) in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1470)

> The class annotated with @CucumberContextConfiguration is passed to springs TestContextManager and subject to the same processing the class would be in JUnit. So this should result in the application context being created with a mocked MyService bean.

In other words, you need to move the `@MockBean` declaration to the `@CucumberContextConfiguration` class and then inject it in your step definition class (for example using `@Autowired`).

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        glue = "xxx",
        features = "classpath:xxx"
)
public class AcceptanceTestSuite {
    @MockBean MyMock mock;
}
```

And then

```
public class ScenarioStepDefinitions {
    @Autowired MyMock mock;

    // ... steps
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@MockBean is not ignored, the bean is mocked but it's not injected, so you can inject it via @inject, this works fine for me :

```
@Inject
@MockBean
private AgentRestClient agentRestClient;
```

Comment: Now the `agentRestClient` is indeed not null, but the injected value is the Spring bean (`AgentRestClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB`) instead of the mock on which I can start defining mocked behavior. This results in a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException`. This is expected, as I don't run the test with `SpringRunner`, but with Cucumber. How do you run your tests?

Comment: You should have the both, the main cucumber test is run with cucumber and your steps should be annotated with springRunner

Comment: I am stuck in Similar situation, the mock object is not getting injected. The service class gets a real object instead of mock as defined by @BogdanMinciu.  Any workarounds ?