# @MockBean injected correctly but with null value on test class

Tags: java, spring, mockito, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am using tests with Cucumber and Spring Boot

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "cucumber" })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    BatchService batchService;

    @MockBean
    S3ClientService s3ClientService;

    @MockBean
    HttpClientService httpClientService;

    @SpyBean
    UndueService undueService;


    @Given("^foo cucumber test$")
    public void foo_cucumber_test() {
        System.out.println("Foo Test");
    }
}
```

When I run/debug my test with a break point on @Given method

[image]

I got this weird behavior, the `@Mockbean`/`@SpyBean` are correctly injected but in the test class its values are `null` !! and I can't run Mockito functions `verify` or `when`

But when I run a test without cucumber

```
@Test
void fooTest() {
    System.out.println("Foo Test");
}
```

It works fine !! the values are not `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, mock beans are created but not **injected** to the test suite. I guess you should put both `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` annotations.

Here is a similar question: [Spring @MockBean not injected with Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347764/spring-mockbean-not-injected-with-cucumber)

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I had the same problem. I found following solution, and seems better than the accepted solution which needs multiple annotations (which actually did not work for me). Adding here for anyone that may find it useful.

Annotate the test class to use MockitExtension as shown below

```
@ExtendWith(value={SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
```